# Getting a Value Error When I Shouldn't Be

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to have my input move on when enter is pushed on a line with only spaces or just a blank, it doesn't work though it gives me a value error once before it gives me the proper return, which in turn seems to append an extra value to my array and screws over the entire program.

```
import math

def getItems():
    quitNow = False
    while not quitNow:
        prepTotal = []
        paintTotal = []
        priceTotal1 = []
        priceTotal1d = []
        priceTotal2 = []
        priceTotal2d = []
        names = []
        loopQuit = False
        index = 1
        while not loopQuit:

            ans = raw_input("Enter a Name and press Enter to Continue\nEnter \"Q\" to Quit and get the Full Price: ")

            if(ans.lower() != "q"):
                innerLoopQuit = False
                names.append(ans)
                print "\nPlease enter your prep hours for " + names[index-1] + ": "
                while not innerLoopQuit:
                    try:
                        inp = raw_input()

                        if(inp == ""):
                            innerLoopQuit = True
                        else:
                            float(inp)
                            prepTotal.append(float(raw_input()))

                    except ValueError:
                        print "Please enter a valid number."
```

Comment: You're calling `raw_input()` again in your `else` clause. Also, `float(inp)` doesn't really do anything if you don't assign it anywhere. Perhaps you mean `prepTotal.append(float(inp))`?

Comment: Can you put this as an answer so I can mark it correct? Somehow I missed that, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `raw_input()` again in your `else` clause. Also, `float(inp)` doesn't really do anything if you don't assign it anywhere. `prepTotal.append(float(inp))` is what you want to do.